# I can't use shift key in dwarf fortress

Tags: dwarf-fortress, keyboard

It just ignores it. If I press shift+'key', it just does whatever 'key' on it's own is. For instance, when I started playing, I couldn't go up or down levels (shift+> and shift+<), but I can use ctrl+5 and weirdly, shift+5 just fine. I think it's because 5 isn't assigned to anything normally. What is this? How do I fix it? It's blocking off a large portion of the game, as I can't access any capital letters in any menu, because pressing shift+theLetter just chooses theLetter on it's own.

(Also - I've tried a different keyboard, capslock and the on-screen keyboard)

Comment: Check your keyboard's language, as it's responsible for symbol layouts (next to the system clock and whatnot).